# Never hide jquery qtip tooltip

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I'm using the qtip nightly version released on 2012. Unfortunately, I have downloaded the min version and, I'm not able to find the version in [qtip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/), And I do not want to upgrade the plugin as well :(

The qtip tooltip seems to close when I click on somewhere outside the tooltip, I want to implement a feature where, when the tooltip is displayed, it never hides, unless I explicitly execute a `.qtip("destroy")` on it. I'm not able to find which method is hiding the qtip.

This link (http://dpaste.com/1208548/) contains the comments from the plugin. It does not seem to have the api callbacks etc.

Comment: it would take modifying the source code of the plugin, there are online tools to un-minify js (such as this: http://jsbeautifier.org/) so use one of those first then if you know what to do from there you can or otherwise post the code

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
$('#myTooltip').qtip({
    // Other options..
    hide: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the hide option.

```
var tipOptions = {
  content: 'Some basic content for the tooltip',
  show: 'focus',
  hide: { 
    when: {
      event: 'unfocus'
    }
  }
};
```

Refer [`jsFiddle Link`](http://jsfiddle.net/ramsunvtech/zzZBM/)